# Were there women inside Bourbaki?

Tags: mathematics-social-history, bourbaki

Bourbaki was founded around 1934, they have a limit age of fifty and many mathematicians have passed through it. According to an [interview](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Elekheng/interviews/ClaudeChevalley.pdf) with Chevalley no women have belonged to the group up to 1985. Due to the importance of the group in the history of mathematics, I wonder if this is the case even to this day.

> There is evidence that there were women in Bourbaki? Maybe Claire Voisin?

Comment: Wikipedia indicates there are no known women who have been members.